# Orthogonal polynomial and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

I read a book about orthogonal polynomials written by Gabor Szego. There is a conclusion:

Let the real-valued functions $f_0(x),f_1(x),\dots,f_l(x)$, where $l$ is finite or infinite, be of the class $L_\alpha^2[a,b]$ and linearly independent. By orthogonalization, there exists one orthogonal set $\phi_0(x),\phi_1(x),\dots,\phi_l(x)$ such that for $n = 0, 1, \dots,l$,
$$
\phi_n(x) = \lambda_{n0} f_0(x) + \cdots + \lambda_{nn} f_n(x), 
\quad 
\lambda_{nn} > 0 
\tag{1.1}
$$
From (1.1), the following explicit representation holds:
$$
\phi_n(x) = (D_{n-1}D_n)^{-\frac{1}{2}} D_n(x) 
\tag{1.2}
$$
for which, for $n \geq 1$,
$$
D_n(x) = \begin{vmatrix} 
(f_0,f_0) & (f_0,f_1) & \cdots & (f_0,f_n) \\ 
(f_1,f_0) & (f_1,f_1) & \cdots & (f_1,f_n) \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
(f_{n-1},f_0) & (f_{n-1},f_1) & \cdots & (f_{n-1},f_n) \\ 
f_0(x) & f_1(x) & \cdots & f_n(x)
\end{vmatrix}
$$
for $n\geq 0$,
$$
D_n = [(f_v,f_\mu)]_{v,\mu=0,1,2,\dots,n}>0
$$
are determinants. We write $D_{-1} = 1$ and $D_0(x) = f_0(x)$.

Then how to prove the relation (1.2)?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.